# Opencart. Add slider to option for item

Tags: php, opencart-3

In opencards there are inputs for adding options, such as checkboxes, text fields. How to add a slider to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without an extension. I suggest you search the marketplace:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension